# babel . --copy-files incorrectly copy node_modules

Tags: babeljs

I have a project structure like the following:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 chung2014  staff    2774 Nov  7 19:13 README.md
-rw-r--r--    1 chung2014  staff      75 Nov 26 23:27 babel.config.js
drwxr-xr-x  588 chung2014  staff   18816 Nov 26 23:01 node_modules
-rw-r--r--    1 chung2014  staff     781 Nov 26 22:25 nodemon.json
-rw-r--r--    1 chung2014  staff  377691 Nov 26 22:08 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--    1 chung2014  staff    1551 Nov 26 23:27 package.json
-rw-r--r--    1 chung2014  staff    2941 Nov 26 23:29 server.js
drwxr-xr-x   11 chung2014  staff     352 Nov 26 23:03 src
drwxr-xr-x    5 chung2014  staff     160 Nov 26 21:55 test
```

if I have all the source code inside the `src` directory, (e.g put server.js into `src` as well), I can have a script `babel src --out-dir dist/ --copy-files` in my package.json to compile the all the source code in `src` to `dist/` directory.

However, due to some restriction, I cannot put my server.js inside `src` directory. So when I try to have a script `babel . --out-dir dist/ --copy-files` in my package.json, I let babel incorrectly copy files in `node_modules` to `dist`, which is not what I want.

So my question is how I can just only compile and copy files from both `server.js` and `src/` to the destination directory `dist/` without copying files in `node_modules/`?

```
$ cat babel.config.js 

const presets = [
  "@babel/preset-env",
];

module.exports = { presets };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to drop `--copy-files` and do `--ignore node_modules`, e.g.

```
babel . --out-dir dist/ --ignore node_modules
```

and you'll also want to ignore `dist/` and `babel.config.js` and anything else in the root that might contain JS files.

```
babel . --out-dir dist/ --ignore node_modules,dist,babel.config.js
```

Realistically, the better option would be for `server.js` to just proxy through to `dist` instead through, so you could do

```
babel src --out-dir dist/
```

and move `server.js` to `src/server.js`. If having a `server.js` is 100% necessary, then have it do `require("./dist/server");`.

Comment: I cannot drop `--copy-files` since I have some resource files that are not js files and I need to copy those to `dist/` as well. Can you explain more what is for `server.js` to just proxy through to `dist`? I don't get the point here.

Comment: `--copy-files` means copy _all_ files, so if you are using `.` then you're explicitly asking to compile `node_modules` too. That means the only option is to not use `.`. Since you asked to compile the `server.js` file, the only option would be to move it inside `src`. If you _must_ have a `server.js` in the root, then having it call through into `dist/` is the only option to load the compiled version.

Answer (score 4):

### New solution available

[`--no-copy-ignored`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#copy-files) is a new argument which allows the value of `--ignore` to be respected when copying files.

### Usage

Example:

```
babel src -d dist --ignore 'src/**/*.spec.js' --copy-files --no-copy-ignored
```

The spec files are not going to be present on the output directory.

---

Source: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6226#issuecomment-590283042

Answer (score 0):

create a script like:

```js
require('fs-extra').copy(
  process.argv.slice(-2).shift(), 
  process.argv.slice(-2).pop(), 
  { filter: (src,dist)=>{ return (src.match(/\.js|\.jsx|stories|test/)===null)} },
  err => { if (err) return console.error (err); console.log ('Copy success!'); 
});
```

and append this to your build command

> && ./scripts/--copy-files src dist/commonjs

the gist:

https://gist.github.com/kmrk/bbc52a4d54b407398aff1695e5b710b7